# Php string char replacement library or method

Tags: php, preg-replace

Is there any library class or method to use not regular expressions and `preg_replace()` for char replacment?

I mean something where I can get an associative array of chars to be replaced in string?

Comment: Can you include your input and expected output?

Comment: input = fhfhf+   output = fhfhf&#43;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php

usage:

```
<?php
$trans = array("h" => "e", "l" => "b", "f" => "c");
echo strtr("hi all, I said hello", $trans);
?>
```

Note, if i understood you, you're not looking for preg_replace or regex char replacement

**edit no.1**
if you need to excape this kind of data, use `htmlentities` or `str_replace`

```
echo htmlentities("kkk+"); //outputs kkk&#43;
str_replace(array('+'), array('&#43;'), "kkk+"); //outputs kkk&#43;
```

Comment: thanks i'm going to accept this as the answer, what i need is to convert entities to ascii chars but htmlspecialchars doesn't works for me :( ... for example i need to convert 'kkk+' to 'kkk&#43;'

Comment: @ispuk strtr won't work in your case because "if from and to have different lengths, the extra characters in the longer of the two are ignored"

Answer (score 2):

If you need to replace more than one char without clever semantics, e.g. just replace them as they are, use:

```
str_replace(array('+'), array('&#43;'), $string);
// when using an associative array
str_replace(array_keys($array), array_values($array), $string);
```

There is specialized function for HTML entities obviously named `htmlentities()`.

You can use arrays in `preg_replace` too:

```
preg_replace(array('/quick/','/brown/'), array('slow', 'bear'), $string);
```

Or even associative arrays:

```
$array = array('/quick/' => 'slow', '/brown/' => 'bear');
preg_replace(array_keys($array), array_values($array), $string);
```

Comment: there is no way to use an associative array in pre_replace?

Comment: htmlentities won't work for me, if i use strtr() it is ok, if i have "+kkk++++" is changed to "&#43;kkk&#43;&#43;&#43;&#43;" so i think is ok .. :P